# Convert a single row to a sparse matrix of NaNs with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Given a dataframe of the form:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
```

I want to move each element at position `[0, i]` in the current dataframe to position `[i, i]` in the new one. So, for this input, my desired output will be:

```
   col1   col2  col3  col4    
0   1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN    2.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN    NaN   3.0   NaN
3   NaN    NaN   NaN   4.0
```

Note that the position has nothing to do with the values of the elements themselves.

I know I can do this with numpy by calling `np.diag`, but that returns a 2D array of 0s, and I cannot replace 0s with NaNs, because some of the diagonal values might also be replaced, if they are *also* 0s.

What's the simplest way to do this with pandas?

Comment: oops, I didn't notice you can have 0s on the diag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]], columns=("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"))
e = np.eye(df.shape[1])
```

**EDITED**:

```
e[e == 0] = np.nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame(e * df.values, columns=df.columns)

print(df1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.0   NaN
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   5.0
```

As a side note, you cannot mix `nan`s and ints; but you probably know, anyway.

Comment: Nice, you can shorten this a bit with `pd.DataFrame(np.eye(df.shape[1]) * df.values, columns=df.columns)`.

Comment: Ah just noticed the replace. Yeah... that's a show stopper... :(

Comment: If replace was a possibility, you would've done this with `pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df.iloc[0].values), columns=df.columns).replace(0, np.nan)` in one step.

Comment: I see, so you're dividing by np.eye.... Looks good but 1) you can cache the value before hand, and 2) you can get rid of the replace call.

Comment: I think it's perfect now.

Comment: Hmm... I would say yes and no. A previous edit before this divided by np.eye which I thought was fine because it resulted in NaNs outside the diagonal. With this method, you are now relying on division by 0, which is an implementation detail and prone to change. Permission to edit?

Comment: Sure, Go ahead. But I do not see the difference. It was a division by the eye, too.

Comment: Your previous edit throws `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  #!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3`, which I feel is a hacky way of arriving at the answer.

Comment: Why not replace 0 first in e, e[e == 0] = np.nan. Then pd.DataFrame(e * df.values, columns = df.columns)

Comment: You could benchmark `pd.DataFrame({c: v} for c, v in df.iloc[0].iteritems())`?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [78]: import pandas as pd

In [79]: import numpy as np

In [80]: small = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4]]))

In [81]: small
Out[81]:
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4

In [82]: a = np.empty((4,4))

In [83]: a.fill(np.nan)

In [84]: np.fill_diagonal(a, small)

In [85]: a
Out[85]:
array([[  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   2.,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,   3.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   4.]])

In [86]: large = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [87]: large
Out[87]:
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: Ah, using `fill_diagonal`, nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Initialize empty dataframe matrix mirror columns of `df`
df_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, columns=df.columns, index=range(len(df.columns)))

for n, v in enumerate(df.iloc[0, :]):  # enumerate each value of first row in `df`.
    df_diag.iat[n, n] = v

>>> df_diag
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```

You may also want your index to match:

```
df_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
for n, v in enumerate(df.iloc[0, :]):  
    df_diag.iat[n, n] = v

>>> df_diag
      col1  col2  col3  col4
col1   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
col2   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN
col3   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
col4   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ? :)

```
df=pd.concat([df]*df.shape[1],axis=0,keys=df.columns)
df.reset_index(level=1,drop=True).apply(lambda x:x[x.index==x.name]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[202]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```

Also, as DYZ mentioned, the 1st method came into my mind is

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values*np.eye(df.shape[1], dtype=int),columns=df.columns).replace({0:np.nan})
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUIC, you could use a comprehension generator.

```
In [1115]: df
Out[1115]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4

In [1116]: pd.DataFrame({c: v} for c, v in df.iloc[0].items())
Out[1116]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```